# Pylance (ReportMissingModuleSource) with Docker

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code

I'm getting the error of missing import when doing import in my Django project, I think it's because it's installed in a Docker Container.

But how can I make it so VSCode somehow knows that the packages are installed? If I select an interpreter of a venv in which I have installed django or other packages it doesn't give me that warning, but I don't think creating an venv and installing all the packages there is the right thing. Or maybe it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to install the packages individually, but if you want to reuse them, you can add the paths of them into the `PYTHONPATH`.

You can do this to modify the `PYTHONPATH`:

1. Add these in the settings.json file to Modify the `PYTHONPATH` in the terminal:

   **"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
   "PYTHONPATH": "xxx/site-packages"
   }**
2. Create a `.env` file under your workspace, and add these settings in it to modify the `PYTHONPATH` for the extension and debugger:

   **PYTHONPATH=xxx/site-packages**

You can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable) to understand the effects of these two configurations.